# PDO - Actualizar datos mediante <select> y validar que no se repita un estado

Tags: php, update, radio

Necesito ayuda con un codigo php que no me funciona.
Explico, en mi codigo cargo fechas de un torneo de futbol (fecha 1, fecha 2,...) y cada una tiene un estado, activo o inactivo. Si el estado es activo en la base de datos tiene que estar guardado con el valor 1, caso contrario debe ser 0. No puede haber dos fechas activas a la vez. 
Al seleccionar uno de los radios buttom y apretar en "actualizar" tiene que cambiar, pero no ocurre nada. Ya he probado y la consulta UPDATE está bien. No sé que otra cosa puede ser.
Agradezco si me pueden ayudar.

```
$response = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM fecha");
$response->execute();
    <table class="pure-table pure-table-horizontal">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>fecha</th>
      <th>estado</th>
    </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody><?php foreach ($response as $t){ ?>
      <tr>

      <td><?php echo $t['numero_fecha']; ?></td>
      <form action="fecha_php.php" method="POST">
      <td>
         <?php  if ($t['estado']==1): ?>
            <input type="radio" name="estado" checked="checked" value="1" />
        <?php else : ?>
          <input type="radio" name="estado" value="0" />

        <?php endif; ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="id_fecha" value="<?php echo $t['id_fecha']; ?>" />
        <?php } ?>
      </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
          <input type="submit" value="actualizar" name="submitt"/>
      </form>
     </table>
```

La consulta sql la realizo en el archivo llamado fecha_php.php

```
    $add = "UPDATE fecha SET estado=:estado WHERE id_fecha=:id_fecha";
  $d = $conn->prepare($add);
  $d->bindParam(':id_fecha', $_POST['id_fecha']);
  $d->bindParam(':estado', $_POST['estado']);
```

La conexión a la base de datos es:

```
    <?php
$server = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'prode-login';
try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database;", $username, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  die('Conexión fracasada: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

Al cargar aparece esto:

[image: Formulario al ingresar]

[image: BASE DE DATOS]

Una vez se desea actualizar al seleccionar uno de los radio buttom se mantienen todos los estados en cero.

Comment: Porfavor añade de donde proviene la varible $conn (que supongo que es donde tienes almacenado tu objeto PDO) para ver si es error puede estar ahí y brindarte una explicación más acertada

Comment: Responderé a tu pregunta pero te aconsejo que coloques de donde proviene esta variable antes mencionada solo para atar cabos sueltos y que ningún moderador vaya a marcarte esta pregunta como mal redactada

Comment: Gracias, ahora lo edito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder darle solución a este planteamiento he tenido que modificar algunas cosas y escribir algo más de código:

1) He vuelto a reestructurar el código HTML ya que estaba muy mal organizado (deberías de repasar como estructurar bien el código HTML.

2) Lo que hice fue cambiar el valor de los input por el id del dato que está recorriendo el `foreach()` en ese momento. Con esto consigo poder obtener los id de las fechas de una manera más fácil a la hora de mandarlos a la consulta UPDATE.

3) He añadido un `<input type="hidden">` para poder obtener también el id de la fecha que actualmente tiene el estado activo (1). Esto con el fin de actualizar este valor a 0 cuando se realice la consulta ya que no puedes tener dos fechas con estado 1.

4)En los `execute()` de cada consulta UPDATE he cambiado los `bindParam()` por un array dentro de la misma función `execute()`. Esto lo hice ya que es más seguro usar un array, hacen la misma función que los `bindParam()` y además, con los bindParam, hay datos que tienen cierta "restricción" a la hora de se mandados. Por ejemplo, no deja mandar números como  0 o 1.

5) Añadí `try{}catch(){}` para poder manejar mejor algún error futuro.

El código de los archivos quedaría de la siguiente manera:

*index.php:*

```
<?php 

    include 'conexión.php';

    $response = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM fecha");
    $response->execute();

 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="fecha_php.php" method="POST">
        <table class="pure-table pure-table-horizontal">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Fecha</th>
                    <th>Estado</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($response as $t): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $t['numero_fecha']; ?></td>
                    <td>
                    <?php if ($t['estado'] == 1): ?>
                        <input type="radio" name="estado" checked value="<?php echo $t['id_fecha']; ?>" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="idEstadoAnterior" value="<?php echo $t['id_fecha'] ?>">
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <input type="radio" name="estado" value="<?php echo $t['id_fecha']; ?>" />
                    <?php endif ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="actualizar" name="submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

*conexion.php:*

```
<?php
    $server = 'localhost';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $database = 'prode-login';
    try {
      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database;", $username, $password);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
      die('Conexión fracasada: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
 ?>
```

*fecha_php.php:*

```
<?php 

    include 'conexión.php';

    $idFecha = $_POST['estado'];

    try {
        $add = "UPDATE fecha SET estado=:estado WHERE id_fecha=:id_fecha";
        $d = $conn->prepare($add);
        $d->execute([
            ":id_fecha" => $idFecha,
            ":estado" => "1"
        ]);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die("Error: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br>on line: " . $e->getLine() . "<br>on file: " . $e->getFile());
    }

    if(isset($_POST['idEstadoAnterior'])){
        $idFechaAnterior = $_POST['idEstadoAnterior'];

        try {
            $add = "UPDATE fecha SET estado=:estado WHERE id_fecha=:id_fecha";
            $d = $conn->prepare($add);
            $d->execute([
                ":id_fecha" => $idFechaAnterior,
                ":estado" => "0"
            ]);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die("Error: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br>on line: " . $e->getLine() . "<br>on file: " . $e->getFile());
        }
    }

    header("Location: index.php");
 ?>
```

Comment: Gracias por los consejos, y he aplicado los cambios que me dijiste pero el error persiste. Se mantienen tal cual los valores en la base de datos. Todos en cero. Si yo cambio en la parte del "if" la condicion por "0" en lugar de "1", todos los valores en mi base de datos pasan a ser 1.

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir imágenes para reforzar tu duda? Necesito ver el mensaje de error que te lanza para poder determinar qué está causando el error

Comment: Agregué algunas imágenes, yo se que es problema en codigo, pero es para que mas o menos entiendas la estructura, yo necesito que en la bdd, "estado"(que es un tinyint) sea 0 o 1, y solo pueda haber uno solo con valor 1.

Comment: ¿De dónde estás obteniendo la variable $response?

Comment: Lo declaro al principio, es un select de todo lo de la tabla fecha

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta. Espero te sirva

Comment: Sos un genio, te agradezco mucho amigo! Hacia mucho estaba tildado en esta parte! Muchisimas gracias y saludos!!

Comment: Para nada, es un gusto ayudar, sabes que para eso estamos aquí en StackOverflow. Practica mucho que todos comenzamos por donde tú estás. Te agradecería que marques esta respuesta como la respuesta a esta pregunta. Un saludo!